# Jenkins docker sudo error when using -u 1000:1000 option for docker run

Tags: docker, jenkins, cicd

I have a docker image to use in a Jenkins pipeline created with the following DockerFile:

```
# base
FROM ros:noetic

# user
WORKDIR /home/user
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash user \
    && echo "user:my_cool_pass" | chpasswd && adduser user sudo \
    && chown user .
USER user
```

and the command `docker build -f DockerFile -t apalomer/test_repo:test_image .`. When I start the docker with `docker run --rm -it apalomer/test_repo:test_image /bin/bash` I can run `sudo su` and enter my password to be root. However, when I start the docker with `docker run --rm -it -u 1000:1000 apalomer/test_repo:test_image /bin/bash`, then I cannot and I get the following error after typing the right password: `user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`. To try to debug the problem I have checked and the users with ID 1000 are root both in the host and the container (the result is the same regardless of how I start the docker container):

```
user@ed0f0dedba47:~$ echo $UID
1000
user@ed0f0dedba47:~$ grep -Po '^sudo.+:\K.*$' /etc/group
user
user@ed0f0dedba47:~$ id -u user
1000
```

Running these commands in the host computer the uid is also 1000, and the user name (which is not user) appears in the sudo group.

The problem is that I cannot find a way for Jenkins to run the docker image without the `-u 1000:1000` and during the pipeline that uses this image, I have to run some sudo commands. The option to use a different user in the container (i.e. remove the last line `User user`) is not an option due to project restrictions.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make Jenkins start the docker without the `-u` option?
2. Is there a way to start the docker with the `-u` option and still run sudo commands?

Comment: You pretty much never need `sudo` in Docker.  If you're running a container, you can use a `docker run -u` option to change its user ID, maybe to root; in a Dockerfile you can switch `USER` as often as you need.

Comment: (Also, `sudo` makes you root already; why `sudo su`?)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `-u` to `-u user:sudo` and now the problem is solved.